# Zapier CLI : How do you clear the value of an input filed when dependent field changes?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

Im building a Zapier App using the Zapier CLI.

I have created 2 dynamic input fields, both populated from an API.

Field 2 (`channelId`) is dependent on the choice in field 1 (`appId`).

```
inputFields: [
 { 
    key: 'appId',
    label: 'App',
    required: true, 
    type: 'text', 
    helpText: 'Choose the App', 
    dynamic: 'app.id.display_name',
    altersDynamicFields:true,
  },
  {
    key: 'channelId',
    label: 'Channel',
    required: true,
    type: 'string',
    helpText: 'Choose the Channel',
    dynamic: 'channel.channel',
  }
]
```

This works fine the first time the user makes choices.

However, if they choose both options, and then change field 1 (`appId`) it does not clear the selection in Field 2 (`channelId`)

If you re open the menu, you see the new choices - so the `perform` function is running in the resource,  but the previous selected value is not cleared - leaving an invalid selection.

How do you ensure that the dependent field is cleared when the field that alters it is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Great question! The `altersDynamicFields` property is a confusingly-named one. It's tied to [custom/dynamic fields](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/50ccdf5747468005f2ec48d2a33c0958528190f3/packages/cli/README.md#customdynamic-fields), where fields are added and removed from the form dynamically. Because `channelId` is always present, it doesn't get recalculated when `appId` is changed.

As a solution, you could *make* `channelId` a custom field. It'll always be there, but it'll be properly invalidated (I *think*) when `appId` changes:

```
inputFields: [
 { 
    key: 'appId',
    label: 'App',
    required: true, 
    type: 'text', 
    helpText: 'Choose the App', 
    dynamic: 'app.id.display_name',
    altersDynamicFields:true,
  },
  // functions are re-run when fields with `altersDynamicFields: true` are changed
  () => [{
    key: 'channelId',
    label: 'Channel',
    required: true,
    type: 'string',
    helpText: 'Choose the Channel',
    dynamic: 'channel.channel',
  }]
]
```